# How router/access point generates Group Master Key (GMK)?

Tags: encryption, wpa2

How router/access point generates Group Master Key (GMK)? Because GMK is the key that is created in the router and dies in the router, how does router derive it? [In this paper](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/usenixsecurity16/sec16_paper_vanhoef.pdf) is written that in standard IEEE 802.11i (WPA2), the router uses a **flawed RNG (Random Number Generator)** that allows attackers to predict all possible group keys.